# Upload file using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

I need to save a PDF file which the user uploads to database as a byte array (in Angular JS). I have tried using the file upload module provided by Angular. It doesnt seem to work for me.I have also tried posting the PDF file through a $http post call of jquery. This method works if I accept the data at the server side as a dynamic object of Newtonsoft. However I need a byte array and I am unable to convert this object to a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

This questions is not really about angular but instead it is, based on your description, about how to upload a file using `WebApi`.

I would recommend your start trying to upload your file using this exmaple:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/03/01/file-upload-and-asp-net-web-api.aspx

When it is ready then adapting it to your angular app.

Comment: I have tried this method but it enables to write to a certain path on the server. What I want is, to send the file in the form of array of bytes to the API controller so that I can save it in SQL database in that format. As a work around I could use this method to write to a path on the server first, then read it as byte array and save it to database. But is there any other faster approach?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a while back. Have a look at this Stack Overflow link.

[Uploading/Downloading Byte Arrays with AngularJS and ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005687/uploading-downloading-byte-arrays-with-angularjs-and-asp-net-web-api)

If you still have some questions, let me know.

I am sending and receiving a lot of byte array data between my clients and servers using Web API. The approach I use is compatible with iPhones, iPad, Android devices, Macs, and Windows PCs/laptops. I haven't checked it on Windows phones yet, but do not expect any problems.

Regards....