# Sending byte collections with form form data to api using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, file, api, byte, uploading

I have to send a byte array to an api along with the field data as shown in the figure.I have a doubt about using the modules provided by angularjs community because its not stating about how the data is transferred and I have little understanding about it.
so I want to post any file uploaded from a button to a byte collection to an api with the form data. here is an image for my api.

[image]

Actually the problem I faced  is changing the file to byte in angular and again finding a module to upload the byte array.
I have seen some of byte uploading techniques but they are quit different compared to what I need.If you have some better ways to look at this please show me some

Answer (score 1):

Dagm,

I do not have enough points to add a comment to your question, so I will start an answer here.

I am using the .NET Web API 2.0 on the server to receive and process the client transmission. Is this an option for you?

I am sure that there are other server options other than Web API, but half of my answer depends on this server-side functionality.

Let me know, and I will try to assist you.

Regards....

I can at least give you some client code that works with angular. I do a lot of client side compaction and compression of data into byte arrays before sending to the server.

Let me know if this would be useful.

Here is some client code.

```js
ItemHttpService.prototype.uploadItem = function ($http, Id, Transaction_Id, FileName, FileExt, File, itemUploadCallback) {
        $http({
            // Web API 2.0 specific. ItemUpload references the ItemUploadController. UploadItems is method name.
            url: 'api/ItemUpload/UploadItems',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream' },
            data: new Uint8Array(File),
            params: {
                // Other params here, including string metadata about uploads
                Id: Id,
                Transaction_Id: Transaction_Id,
                FileName: FileName,
                FileExt: FileExt
            },
            transformRequest: [] // Used to handle the byte array data.
        }).success(function (response, status) {// This is one example of how I handled a response.
            if (status === 200) {
                itemUploadCallback(response); // As I recall, the response is a JSON stringified result. 
            } else {
                itemUploadCallback('');
            }
        }).error(function (status) {
            itemUploadCallback(JSON.stringify("Your error handling here"));
        });
    };

Not sure what the tblPeriodical_Transaction is. Can you elaborate?
```

Comment: After taking some of you adjustment and tbl_transaction as a json param it go me going some how ,thanks